# sammyjs cannot go back to a route i accessed before

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, sammy.js

I'm new to SammyJS and I am running into an issue. I have my routes working, however when I access 1, and then i go to the other. It works. The problem is when I try to go back to the first route that I visited. I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and sammyjs.

Here is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
debugger;
; (function ($) {
    var app = $.sammy(function () {
        debugger;
        this.get('#/PartIndex', function () {
            var routing = new Routing('@Url.Content("~/")', '#testing', 'CustomerDetail/CustomerEditDetailPartial');
            routing.init();
        });
        this.get('#/ECheckbook', function () {
            debugger;
            var routing = new Routing('@Url.Content("~/")', '#testing', 'CustomerDetail/CustomerEditDetailPartial');
            routing.init();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        app.run()
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```
<div class="page-container">
        <a href="#/ECheckbook">Margin</a>
<br />
<a href="#/PartIndex">Main</a>
    <div id="testing">

    </div>
```

in my routing.js
    var Routing = function (appRoot, contentSelector, defaultRoute) {

```
function getUrlFromHash(hash) {
    debugger;
    var secondString = hash.split('/')[2];
    var url = hash.replace('#/', '').replace(secondString + '/', '');
    if (url === appRoot)
        url = defaultRoute;
    return url;
}

return {
    init: function () {
        Sammy(contentSelector, function () {
            this.get(/\#\/(.*)/, function (context) {
                var url = getUrlFromHash(context.path);
                context.load(url).swap();
            });
        }).run('#/');
    }
};
```

}